# Colorir pontos específicos em Ggplot - R

Tags: r, ggplot2

Estou fazendo uma análise gráfica dos dados do pacote `gapminder`. Logo, eu fiz o seguinte código:

```
library('gapminder')
dados6 <- gapminder

ggplot(gapminder, aes(x = continent, y = lifeExp)) +
  geom_boxplot(outlier.colour = "hotpink") +
  geom_jitter(position = position_jitter(width = 0.1, height = 0), alpha = 1/4)
```

Em que produziu o gráfico abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Contudo, eu quero colorir com a cor verde os pontos referentes ao Brasil.
Como eu posso fazer isso?

Atenciosamente.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pode fazer isso com mais uma `geom_`, a `geom_point`. No entanto, para ter só os pontos referentes ao Brasil, tem que selecionar um subconjunto dos dados, neste caso com `subset`.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)
library('gapminder')


gapminder %>%
  group_by(continent) %>%
  mutate(ymax = quantile(lifeExp, 3/4) + IQR(lifeExp),
         ymin = quantile(lifeExp, 1/4) - IQR(lifeExp),
         out = lifeExp < ymin | lifeExp > ymax) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = continent, y = lifeExp)) +
  geom_boxplot(outlier.colour = "hotpink") +
  geom_jitter(aes(y = ifelse(out, NA, lifeExp)),
              position = position_jitter(width = 0.1, height = 0), alpha = 1/4) +
  geom_point(data = subset(gapminder, country == 'Brazil'),
             aes(x = continent, y = lifeExp),
             position = position_jitter(width = 0.1),
             colour = "green", alpha = 1/2)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Eu não entendi os outliers nesta visualização e na do AP. Note que há um ponto preto ao lado de cada outlier rosa. Parece que ambos `geom_jitter` e `geom_boxplot` estão plotando os outliers, mas apenas o `geom_boxplot` os pinta de rosa. Acredito que haja uma duplicação desnecessária destes pontos aberrantes, mas apenas deles. Ou seja, o `geom_jitter` acaba fazendo com que os outliers apareçam todos dobrados, levando o usuário a acreditar que há o dobro de outliers neste conjunto de dados.

Comment: @MarcusNunes Feito, creio que agora está certo.

Comment: Excelente, Rui!

Comment: Bem sinalizado!